# SQL Server Management Studio - Finding all non empty tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Is there a way for SQL Server Management Studio Express How to list all the non empty tables? I have over 100 tables to go through and check for data.

Comment: In a single DB or multiple DBs?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could try using `sysindexes` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`:)

```
SELECT 'Table Name'=convert(char(25),t.TABLE_NAME),
      'Total Record Count'=max(i.rows)
FROM sysindexes i, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
WHERE t.TABLE_NAME = object_name(i.id)
      and t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
GROUP BY t.TABLE_SCHEMA, t.TABLE_NAME
HAVING max(i.rows)>0
ORDER BY 'Total Record Count' DESC
```

Comment: i ended using thos code because i have no idea what i am doing.. i just added databasename.INFORM...

Comment: I like how you include tables with fewer than 0 rows ;)

Comment: @JoshNoe, I fixed it. Can't believe it stayed like this for so long.

Answer (score 5):

[Morris Miao's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17748653/485561) uses the deprecated [sys.sysindexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190283.aspx) view; and performs the join to [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms186224.aspx) on the basis of table name, which is not guaranteed to be unique; even within a database.

[Simon's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17748497/485561) is not scoped to the current database; but can be refined through the use of [sys.tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx):

```
SELECT r.table_name, r.row_count, r.[object_id]
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT OBJECT_NAME(s.[object_id]) table_name, SUM(s.row_count) row_count, s.[object_id]
    FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats s
    WHERE s.index_id in (0,1)
    GROUP BY s.[object_id]
) r on t.[object_id] = r.[object_id]
WHERE r.row_count > 0
ORDER BY r.table_name;
```

Comment: This approach does not work unless the user is a Server Admin user.  This will yield "VIEW DATABASE STATE permission denied in database '<db name>'.

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
WITH TableRows AS
(
   SELECT 
      SUM(row_count) AS [RowCount], 
      OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS TableName
   FROM 
      sys.dm_db_partition_stats
   WHERE 
      index_id = 0 OR index_id = 1
   GROUP BY 
      OBJECT_ID
)

SELECT *
FROM TableRows
WHERE [RowCount] > 0
```

Comment: How about getting the nonempty tables in one database?

Comment: @PeterSun: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39484816/485561).

Answer (score 3):

Lets say Tables can be of two types.

1. Clustered Table ( Tables having a Clustered Index )
2. Heap Tables (
       Tables not having a Clustered Index )

All tables in  SQL Server are divided into partitions. So that all table will have atleast one partition .

In [`sys.partitions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-partitions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), there exists one row for each partition of all tables.

These rows in `sys.partitions` contains information about **number of rows** in that partition of the corresponding table.

Since all tables in SQL Server contain aleast one partition, we can get the information about number of rows in a table from `sys.partitions`.

```
SELECT
        OBJECT_NAME(T.OBJECT_ID) AS TABLE_NAME,
        SUM(P.ROWS)  AS TOTAL_ROWS
FROM
        SYS.TABLES T
INNER JOIN 
        SYS.PARTITIONS P 
        ON T.OBJECT_ID = P.OBJECT_ID
WHERE 
        P.INDEX_ID IN (0,1)
GROUP BY 
        T.OBJECT_ID
HAVING 
        SUM(P.ROWS) > 0
```

While taking sum of rows in different partitions, we are considering `index_id` **(0,1)**

- `index_id = 0 for Heap`
- `index_id = 1 for Clustered index`
- `index_id > 1 are for nonclustered index.`

A table can have either one clustered index or none.

But that is not the case with nonclustered index. A table can have multiple nonclustered indexes.
So we cannot use those `index_id` while summing rows.

- Heap Tables will be having `index_id = 0`
- Clustered Tables will be having `index_id = 1`

Comment: This is the only query that can be run without requiring the user to be a Server Administrator (or be explicitly granted the VIEW DATABASE STATE privilege on the database).

Answer (score 1):

One could also use "Object Explorer Details (F7)", navigate to the "Tables"-Folder of the database of interest and set the Object Explorer Details to show thw Row Count (right click on the headers)

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight improvement to [@jophab's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50602998/241211). It will show schema for tables as well as compare `rows = 0` using `sys.partitions`.

```
SELECT 
    sch.name as SchemaName,
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON t.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch
    on t.schema_id = sch.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND p.rows = 0
GROUP BY 
    sch.name,t.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    sch.name,t.Name
```