# SqlServer - Get all tables that has data ( are not empty )

Tags: sql, sql-server

The question is simple:

**Is it possible to retrive all the tables that are not empty ?**

I need a query to list the tables. Is there a way ?

Thanks to support

Comment: have you had a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748417/sql-server-management-studio-finding-all-non-empty-tables or https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47726/how-to-query-a-database-for-empty-tables

Comment: possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980622/sql-server-2008-i-have-1000-tables-i-need-to-know-which-tables-have-data?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Management Studio - Finding all non empty tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748417/sql-server-management-studio-finding-all-non-empty-tables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Script To get all tables with non empty records

```
    USE [Your database Name]
    Go
    SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS [SchemaName],
            [Tables].name AS [TableName]
            --SUM([Partitions].[rows]) AS [TotalRowCount]
    FROM sys.tables AS [Tables]
    JOIN sys.partitions AS [Partitions]
        ON [Tables].[object_id] = [Partitions].[object_id]
        AND [Partitions].index_id IN ( 0, 1 )
    -- WHERE [Tables].name = N'name of the table'
    GROUP BY SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id), [Tables].name
    HAVING SUM([Partitions].[rows]) >0
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different than @Sreenu131 answer as it is using sys.partitions .rows property to find

> p.rows > 0

```
SELECT 
    sch.name as SchemaName,
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON t.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch
    on t.schema_id = sch.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND p.rows > 0
GROUP BY 
    sch.name,t.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    sch.name,t.Name
```